# Why does BufferedReader lines() method, a stream, never ends?

Tags: java, java-8, stream

A stream obtaining data from a BufferedReader seems to be asynchronously calling the consumer, which is a great feature.

Why is this? It seems the JVM has a thread calling the lines().forEach() method in the background.

```java
   public class P {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
           while (true) {
               Thread.sleep(1000);
               java.lang.System.out.println("Running");
           }
       }
   }

   class StreamQuestion {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
           ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().command("java", "P");
           pb.environment().put("CLASSPATH", P.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
           java.lang.Process p = pb.start();
           /**
            * Question: Why does this program not end? Instead, it keeps printing "Running".
            * */
           new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())).lines().forEach(java.lang.System.out::println);
       }
   }
```

Comment: You are pointing out great things, the inner workings and the contracts, which is what I'm trying to pin down.

Comment: Turned comment into an answer.

Comment: Why do you assume it is async?

Comment: If you add a system out after new BufferedReader(), it will print.

Comment: The `getPath()` method of the URL class is not the correct way to obtain a file name from a URL.  If the path has spaces or other characters which aren’t allowed in URLs, you will get a string which is not a valid file name.  The correct way to get a file name would be `Paths.get(codeSource.toURI()).toString()`.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong, if I put a statement after new BufferedReader(), it won't print. So yeah, it's sync.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question is unclear, and seems to state facts that aren't true.

> stream never ends

The stream will end when the process terminates, and all output has been read. Since that never happens, you're right, the stream never ends.

> Why does this program not end? Instead, it keeps printing "Running".

Because the process never ends and keeps printing "Running" in a `while (true) {...}` forever loop. That's what you wrote the code to do, so that's what it does. Why is that confusing you, that the program does exactly what you told it to do?

> asynchronously calling the consumer

No, that's done synchronously, unless you make it *parallel*.

> JVM has a thread calling the lines().forEach() method in the background

No, that is done in the main thread, again unless you make it *parallel*, which you didn't.

Comment: And just to make that clear: even if you turn the stream to parallel, the terminal operation will not return before the operation completed, so if it spawns asynchronous operations, it will wait for their completion.

Comment: I think I have my answer. I was assuming the forEach came back right away but it does not. It is synchronous and will keep printing until the terminal operation. Does this sound about right?

Comment: @RodrigoGomez Correct, `forEach(...)` doesn't return until the entire stream has been processed. Nowhere in the documentation does it say that any of the [*terminal operations*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) will return immediately, so I don't know why you'd think that. Sounds like you need to read up on how Java streams work.

Comment: I'm hoping with this example it will help others understand the run-time behavior of a background process which could be feeding standard error and out. With this new understanding, I can better think about processing these two streams in parallel...

Comment: The linked document is even explicit about it: “*In almost all cases, terminal operations are eager, completing their traversal of the data source and processing of the pipeline before returning. Only the terminal operations `iterator()` and `spliterator()` are not;*…”